# SDL Web 8 (8.1) Installer not showing Outbound Emailing Services options

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, outbound-email, audience-manager

As per [SDL Web 8 documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-3975B503-8407-493C-955C-530FF2A5D6BC&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-3975B503-8407-493C-955C-530FF2A5D6BC.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3975B503-8407-493C-955C-530FF2A5D6BC) Outbound E-mail is deprecated but still available in the version 8.1.1 and should be available  with the installation media. Although I am not able to find the Emailing Services options during installation of Outbound E-mail. I checked the Advance installation mode also. May be I am missing something. Any suggestion / guidance will be really helpful.

Regards

Comment: @atila, thanks for correcting the question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the LEGACY_VISIBLE switch on the installer.

For details, check this chapter on the documentation, aptly named "[Running the installer to install Outbound E-mail on the Content Manager server](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9553B0AD-5206-48C7-93AE-CAF768719FD3)"

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow suggested steps and revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer in legacy mode